# Is there any way to replace nested For loop with Higher order methods in scala

Tags: scala

I am having a mutableList and want to take sum of all of its rows and replacing its rows with some other values based on some criteria. Code below is working fine for me but i want to ask is there any way to get rid of nested for loops as for loops slows down the performance. I want to use scala higher order methods instead of nested for loop. I tried flodLeft() higher order method to replace single for loop but can not implement to replace nested for loop

```
def func(nVect : Int , nDim : Int) : Unit = {
  var Vector = MutableList.fill(nVect,nDimn)(math.random)
  var V1Res =0.0
  var V2Res =0.0
  var V3Res =0.0
  for(i<- 0 to nVect -1) {
    for (j <- i +1 to nVect -1) {
      var resultant = Vector(i).zip(Vector(j)).map{case (x,y) => x + y}

      V1Res = choice(Vector(i))
      V2Res = choice(Vector(j))
      V3Res = choice(resultant)
      if(V3Res > V1Res){
       Vector(i) = res
      }
      if(V3Res > V2Res){
        Vector(j) = res
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The big performance problem here is accessing elements of a `List` by index. Change `MutableList` to `Array` and it should be much faster.

Comment: If you're looking for performance, might I suggest using a purpose built numerical processing library such as Breeze: https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze

Comment: @Tim yes this is also a valid point but major concern is with for loop, for loop are major reason to hurdle when we talk about parallelism.

Comment: We are not talking about parallelism. Or rather, you don't mention parallelism anywhere in your question. Perhaps you need to re-think what you are asking? Also, there are no loops in this code, just function calls to `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no "for loops" in this code; the `for` statements are already converted to `foreach` calls by the compiler, so it is already using higher-order methods. These `foreach` calls could be written out explicitly, but it would make no difference to the performance.

---

Making the code compile and then cleaning it up gives this:

```
def func(nVect: Int, nDim: Int): Unit = {
  val vector = Array.fill(nVect, nDim)(math.random)

  for {
    i <- 0 until nVect
    j <- i + 1 until nVect
  } {
    val res = vector(i).zip(vector(j)).map { case (x, y) => x + y }

    val v1Res = choice(vector(i))
    val v2Res = choice(vector(j))
    val v3Res = choice(res)

    if (v3Res > v1Res) {
      vector(i) = res
    }
    if (v3Res > v2Res) {
      vector(j) = res
    }
  }
}
```

Note that using a single `for` does not make any difference to the result, it just looks better!

At this point it gets difficult to make further improvements. The only parallelism possible is with the inner `map` call, but vectorising this is almost certainly a better option. If `choice` is expensive then the results could be cached, but this cache needs to be updated when `vector` is updated.

If the `choice` could be done in a second pass after all the cross-sums have been calculated then it would be much more parallelisable, but clearly that would also change the results.